# How to disable record edit but allow using of controls in Access split form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a split form with some buttons (cmd) and combo boxes (cbo) at top. The form is based on the table with clients' properties. Question is how to lock records from editing, but allow using cmd and cbo.

Mostly edit is disabled with `me.allowedits = false`.
When `.allowedits = false`, it is impossible to trigger `on_click` events, so buttons and combos are not working.

I have tried a solution using temporary toggle of `.allowedits` on `getFocus/lostFocus` events.

On the first look, it works. On button click we have `getFocus-edits` enabled first, and can use button or cbo. Any new button triggers lostfocus event first and we have initial locked state.

But this doesn't always work. If user tries to edit record after using a control, `lostFocus` is not triggering and editing is still allowed.

Another popular solution is about locking some controls one by one. This way is quite complicated when there is a lot of fields and buttons.

Maybe is it possible to dynamically switch form recordset mode from dynaset to snapshot? Or to change something to have button `lostfocus` event before fields edit? Or maybe there is a better way to lock records but not buttons? Help will be appreciated.

EDITED after discussion.
With a help of community, method with changing `.RecordsetType` was considered as the best. I've tested it, and posted here a code.

Then I met new restriction. Code works perfect with toggle button.
But when I use it in form `AfterUpdate` event, editing of records is still possible, despite the fact, that `Me.RecordsetType` is set to Snapshot.
(My wish was to switch off editing mode again after each editing done).

For now, I have no idea, why `Snapshot` mode not locking edit when is set in `AfterUpdate` procedure.

I have maken a bypass. I figured out, that in Form_Current event, `Snapshot` works.
So, bypass code:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
 'Bypass for locking edit after change record
 TempVars("AftUpd") = True  
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Current()
 'Bypass for locking edit after change record 
 If TempVars("AftUpd") = True Then
    TempVars.Remove ("AftUpd")    
    ' release AllowEdit-ToggleButton, and making this button release actions
    tbuAllowEdit.Value = False
    Call tbuAllowEdit_Click
 End If
End Sub
```

This works, so I'll stop on this.

Still, if somebody have thoughts, why `Snapshot` method is not working in `AfterUpdate`, or how to fix this, please share.

Comment: You can't both alow edit and prevent edit. Adjusting a bound combobox will edit the form. So, rethink your concept.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but whenever I have a large set of controls that need to all be locked/unlocked I usually use the Tag property. Then I write a sub that loops through all controls and checks for whatever specific tag I assigned them.

Comment: To prevent edits, set the form's Recordset Type to Snapshot in the properties pane - data tab.

Comment: A form with AllowEdits set to no still allows button Click events but not combobox selection. So alternative is to lock/disable controls. Conditional Formatting can disable textboxes and comboboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all hints provided. It really helps.
As a result, I can say, all 3 methods beyond `getFocus`/`lostFocus` can be used.

No 3 - using control lock. We can lock all fields of the text type, and leave free all others - it is simply enough with cycle. Not sure, how to do this with conditional formatting, but probably it is possible.

No 2 - as buttons are not locked (I missed this), we can replace toggle buttons with button plus indicator. (in fact, i need toggle buttons). This solution regards only toggle buttons, not checkboxes.

And No 1, probably, winner:
switching `.RecordsetType` from `Dynaset` to `Snapshot` and back. It locks only records, not other controls. Almost ideal, no compromise in design or code.
In fact, this is Microsoft recommended method to lock edit:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/recordsettype-property-dbe9dd7a-cc73-4539-aaa7-9e6b55034052

The only drawback is when switching, pointer position always goes to the first record.
But looks like this can be fixed with simple code (found in ms.docs access site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/move-to-specific-record-from-combo-box-selection , method 1).

Tested with one toggle button, works perfect.
Resulting code is

```
Private Sub Toggle7_Click()
 Dim rs
 Dim IdRem
 IdRem = Me.ID
 If Toggle7 = True Then
    Me.RecordsetType = 0 ' allow  edits
 Else
    Me.RecordsetType = 2
 End If
 Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
 rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Nz(IdRem)
 If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
 Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

After implementing in my real base, I've met another restriction of this method. Described this in main question EDITED section.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the 'Locked'-property for each individual text-box to 'no'.

And leave the 'Locked'-property for the buttons and combo boxes to 'yes'.

In design view: You can multi-select the controls and lock them all.

Or in VBA, you could use the trick with 'tag' as Bryan Rock wrote, or give the controls a name that starts with '*Lock*' to recognise them in a loop.